# How can I make sure about existence of certain java class/interface in program level?

Tags: java, annotations, strategy-pattern

I am using simple strategy pattern for my project. 
I need to add each concrete class of strategy interface in certain enum for later use.
for convenience reason,  I am using a temporary interface which should be replaced later rather than implement every concrete classes to finish design first.

here is simple code that I tried.

```
public interface Strategy{
    public void execute();
}

public interface NeedToImplement extends Strategy {

}

public enum strategyInfo {
    A(ConcreteStrategyA.class, "blah blah" ), 
    B(ConcreteStrategyB.class, "blah~~" ),
    C(NeedToImplement.class, "blah~~");
}
```

So far, code itself won't be a matter if I am the only person who manage this code and do not forget implementing every classes. 
but this is team job, and I will split each of implementation for my team member so, if any of our team member forget implementing any class, It would cause disaster even in runtime.

I wanna make sure to be notified if `NeedToImplement` is exist as soon as I run a program by Exception or Error(like I can get a warning from `@Deprecated` )
while I can still compile without any compile error from code.

First idea come up in my mind was using custom annotation for `NeedToImplement` interface. but actually I am not sure about further details.
plz elaborate details if my idea is valid.
if not, any suggestion which is better than Ctrl+F will be appreciated as well.

Comment: You could mark it as deprecated, and you should get a warning.

Comment: As for anything better than Ctrl-F: in Eclipse click on NeedToImplement and press Ctrl-Shift-G.

Comment: Thx for the mention, like you mentioned , Deprecated only generate warning. Is there any other way to make a custom Annotation which will generate Exception instead of warning ?

Comment: If you want to generate an exception at compile time - have invalid code. Put the _real_ class name there and it won't compile. Or better yet, add unit tests that execute each strategy - they will fail to instansiate the ones that aren't concrete.

Comment: Do you want to make it not compile, or do you want to make it compile but throw an exception at runtime?

Comment: I revised my original question. I would not be surprised if the way I am looking for is impossible but thing is... how to raise immediate runtime exception/error rather than real runtime error(which will cause disaster) like I can get a warning from @Deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do would be to:

1. Mark your temporary interfaces with the `@Depreceated` tag in your [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html). You could also provide information as to what/when developers should be using.
2. Another thing you could do to check for the existence of the interface, would be to wire up a simple unit test using something such as [`JUnit`](http://junit.org/) which would be run when your code compiles. Most compilation tools, such as ANT or Maven should allow you to attach test scripts at the end of compilation cycles. If the test fails, then, your temporary interface would be still there.

Comment: I think the unit test approach is a no-brainer. If the OP uses a CI (everyone uses a CI, _right_?) then it would flag up unfinished work immediately.

Answer (score 0):

you could make new instances of each class in your execute() method, that I guess would be implemented for each action or similar in the project

you create an empty class for each class you will implement later and in each constructor you place a warning at your choice